# JSF reload the same function several times

Tags: jsf

I have a problem with JSF.

I make a page with JSF and dataTable of primefaces, but I realized that when I use a var into datatable, JSF reload a same get method many times.
I don't know if because the JSF or my Program, someone can help me?

```
 <p:dataTable var="Usuario" value="#{usuarioBean.listaUsuario}"
                             paginator="true" rows="10" selection="#{usuarioBean.usuario}"
                             rowKey="#{Usuario.id}"
                             id="dataTable"
                             paginatorPosition="bottom">
                    <p:column headerText="ID" style="width: 10px">
                        <h:outputText value="#{Usuario.id}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Nome">
                        <h:outputText value="#{Usuario.nome}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="E-mail">
                        <h:outputText value="#{Usuario.email}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Telefone" style="width: 10px">
                        <h:outputText value="#{Usuario.telefone}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Editar" style="width: 10px;">
                        <p:commandLink  id="btnEditar" action="#{usuarioBean.ChamareditarUsuario()}" ajax="false" title="Editar">     
                            <h:graphicImage  value="/resources/img/editar.png" style="position: relative; top: 25%; left: 25%;" />     
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{Usuario}" target="#{usuarioBean.usuario}" /> 
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Excluir" style="width: 10px;">                                                 
                        <p:commandLink  id="btnDeletar" title="Deletar" action="#{usuarioBean.deletarUsuario()}" update="dataTable">     
                            <h:graphicImage  value="/resources/img/deletar.png" style="position: relative; top: 25%; left: 25%;"/>                                                
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{Usuario}" target="#{usuarioBean.usuario}" /> 
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column  selectionMode="single" width="1%"/>
                </p:dataTable>




@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UsuarioBean {

private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
private String campo;
private String valor;
private List<Usuario> listaUsuario;
private String acesso;
private List<Acesso> listaAcesso;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can understand a little more in this question:

[Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)

Basiclly, a getter is called several times, is part of the JSF lifecycle.

Cheers.

Comment: Click on the text that says 
Why JSF call getters multiple times
or click in this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times

Comment: i dont see the link... tks

Answer (score 0):

Show your `usuarioBean` - what Scope does it have?

If it has no Scope (or the wrong scope), the bean will be reconstructed, every time you access `#usuarioBean.listaUsuario`- which will happen 4 times per iteration in your example.

To avoid that, make it `@RequestScoped`, so it lives as long as the current Request.

Sidenode: `h:datatable` is not the primefaces component. it would be `p:datatable` with the right Namespace imported.

Comment: i put the correct code now. i use request scope and i have this problem with this scope....